# Compiling LibOpenShot -> cannot find zmq.hpp [Win/msys64]

Tags: python, c, windows, development-environment, openshot

I'm trying to compile LibOpenShot for Windows, using this guide: https://github.com/OpenShot/libopenshot/wiki/Windows-Build-Instructions

All goes well untill I enter the cmake command for building libopenshot. it gives me this error:
In file included from X:/libs/libopenshot/libopenshot/src/Clip.cpp:23:
X:/libs/libopenshot/libopenshot/src/ZmqLogger.h:22:10: fatal error: zmq.hpp: No such file or directory
22 | #include <zmq.hpp>
|          ^~~~~~~~~

It was installed through packman as instructed. When looking in c:\msys64\mingw64\include\ I can find a zmq.h but not a zmq.hpp. So something is wrong. I cannot find a zmq.hpp at all anywhere in the c:\msys64.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded zmq.hpp from:

https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp

And manually copied it to c:\msys64\mingw64\include\